# Memory Level Warning and Leaks in iPad Application

Tags: memory-management, uikit, uibutton, ipad

I am making one iPad application in which I have to make two view controller and then adding UIButton, UIImageView, Video, Audio, WebView, PooverView in the view dynamically and navigate between two views continuously using pushViewController / Popviewcontroller methods of navigation view controllers.

I have also manage all the IBOutlet to be free in viewDidUnload() method and also managed the dealloc() method as per the apple's standard. Every created object I am releasing wherever required. But I am getting memory level 2 warning when doing push/pop between view more than 100 times continuously. And here I attached the leaks I am getting in iPad device. And it is not specified where in the application leaks exists but I am getting few leaks stated as follows:

(1) UIControlTargetAction
(2) GeneralBlock-16
(3) _NSArrayM
(4) UIButtonContent
(5) UIButtonLabel
(6) GeneralBlock-96
(7) _NSCFDictionary

[image: Memory Leak Using Leaks tool in XCode]

Can anyone please help me to solve this critical problem. This is very critical situation for my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe share your code with somebody would be helpful. Then that person can look at the code with a fresh look. Dont know if that is possible for your project...

Comment: Hello Mats, Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Post your code on GitHub or somewhere and i will take look if you want.